# Cockcroft-Walton voltage multiplier can be built with electrolytic capacitor or not

Tags: electrolytic-capacitor, multiplier

i know that capacitor is usually work with ac supply as in dc acts as a open circuit after charging , so can electrolyte capacitor be used in Cockcroft-Walton voltage multiplier , or it will explode due to sine wave source supply ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each capacitor only sees one polarity of voltage across it, so electrolytics are fine as far as that goes. Pay attention to ripple current ratings, however.

Comment: each capacitor to charge see some half wave in the same polarity but to charge the other one the one who charged with the supply are with reversed polarity together they charge the second capacitor to double the voltage , if we talk about  voltage doubler for simple example

Comment: like this image http://www.creative-science.org.uk/mult/2multa.gif

Comment: The first capacitor sees both polarities

Comment: @Dean: If you believe that's true, then you'll have to explain in detail. You might want to write a separate answer so that you can use diagrams, etc. The fact that you apply an AC voltage to one end of a capacitor does not necessarily imply that the capacitor sees both polarities across it. The diodes prevent that from happening.

Comment: @DaveTweed: Look at the picture in the comments here by Ahmed. If you apply positive to the bottom input on the left, it goes right, up through the diode D1, and charges the capacitor C1. But supposing you first start with a positive on the top input: It pushes positive right, into C1, on past D2, down into C2 and back, to the other input, so you are charging both C1 and C2 in series. (I may well be wrong here; setting this up to actually measure, will report back later).

Comment: @Dean: OK, but that is a transient condition that lasts for at most one half cycle.

Comment: @DaveTweed yeah. I'm wary about them, having had one explode on me when reversed. On a related issue, another interesting thought is if it makes sense to put a bigger front  capacitor, since it is the 'pump', and in each cycle the charge is pushed across to potentially many other capacitors. To invest in say 100X multiplier, having a bigger pump capacitor seems logical at first sight.

Comment: Here are some measurements I made with a 6X multiplier with 400V 100uF electrolytics and 1N4006 diodes. I took the voltage across the first capacitor after applying +9.67V and -9.67V alternately with a '9V battery':

-4.5V, +9.3V, +1.2V, +9.3V, +2.8V, +9.3V, +3.7V, +4.3V

So the first charge is approximately half the input voltage, in the wrong direction across the first capacitor. All the other capacitors I measured were always charged with +ve voltage on the correct terminal.

Comment: @DaveTweed There should be another +9.3V in between the last two readings in the previous comment. That part is consistent. If I go fast enough, I can get 52V across the whole thing by moving across the battery back and forth as fast as I can (1 Hz)!